# Python input loops based on user selections for event scoring

Tags: python

The idea of the program is as follows;

1) Users are asked to select either 1 or 2

2) If one is selected, the user is prompted to enter the score. If 2 is selected the user should be able to view the scores.

3) After the user has entered or viewed a score they should be able to add another score or view scores. Typing `Y` should bring them back to the beginning of the program. `N` Should say they can close the program, or close it.

At the moment, the number selections work for the score entry but I'm not sure how to make it so that the program restarts is the user wishes to add or view more scores.

Here's the program in its current state;

```
print ("Type 1 to a add a score.")
print ("Type 2 to view scores.")
action = input("Please type a number: ")
if action == "1":
    print ("Enter a score?")
    eventscore = int(input ("Please type their score: ") 
    score = eventscore
    f = open("scores.txt", "a")
    f.write(eventscore)
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    print("The score for" , score, "has been saved.")
elif action == "2":
    print ("Type 1 to view all scores.")
    print ("Type 2 to view scores for a specific team.")
    scorecheck = input("Please type a number: ")
    if scorecheck == "1":
        f = open("scores.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            allscores = f.readlines()
        print(allscores)
    f.close
elif scorecheck == "2": 
        teamcheck= input ("Please enter the team name: ")

while True:
    while True:
        answer = input('Want to add a new score or view existing scores? (Y/N): ')
        if answer in ('Y', 'N'):
            break
        print ("Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print ("You can now close the program.")
        break
```

Currently the program is able to start, ask the user to pick if they want to add or view scores and then ask if they want to add/view more or close the program. If the user enters 'Y' the program should completely restart, but it still needs to have the loops for adding/viewing. If they type `N` the program should close.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know how to get a loop on the overall program when it already contains multiple loops.

Comment: Flat is better than nested...no need for two while loops here

Comment: Could you possibly provide an answer because I'd tried that but to no avail, thanks @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    ans = input("Enter option (y, Y):")
    if ans == "":
        print("finished - exit program")
        break
    if ans in ['y', 'Y']:
        askQuestion()

def askQuestion():
    ...top bit of your code
```

On my mobile so just peudocode provided. There's likley a better way than this. As said in chess if you find a good move look for a better one.
Also its canonical to write opening a file inside a `with` context managerlike so:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write..etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a go